# IMagick check lightness image

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

I need to be able to write some text automatically inside an image.  According to the image lightness, the script must write in white or black.

So how do I check the lightness/darkness of an image with Imagick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// Load the image
$imagick = new Imagick("image.jpg");
// convert to HSL - Hue, Saturation and LIGHTNESS
$imagick->transformImageColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_HSL);
// Get statistics for the LIGHTNESS
$Lchannel = $imagick->getImageChannelMean(imagick::CHANNEL_BLUE);
$meanLightness = $Lchannel['mean']/65535;
printf("Mean lightness: %f",$meanLightness);
```

---

If you want to do undercoloured text, per Fred's suggestion, you can do that in PHP with:

```
$image = new Imagick("image.jpg");
$draw  = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('#ffffff');
$draw->setFontSize(24);
$draw->setTextUnderColor('#ff000080');
$image->annotateImage($draw,30,50,0,"Undercoloured Text");
$image->writeImage('result.jpg');
```

[image]

Comment: I am surprised, solution looks so easy. Thought that would be much more complicated. Thank you very much.

Comment: It can get more complicated. If you have an image with say two thirds light sky and dark ground and you have the write on the ground you want the text light; but the average for the whole image may say to use a dark text? In this case you want the lightness where the text will be.

Comment: @Bonzo You make a good point. If this is an issue, OP can make a copy of image and crop it using `cropImage()` to the area where he wants to add the text and then run the statistics on that selected, cropped area.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just create a text image on some background color and overlay that on the image. Or use -undercolor with -draw or -annotate. That way, you do not have to worry about the color of the image. Or you could specify the region where you want to write text over, then get the average lightness of that region. Then test if the region is brighter or darker than mid-gray. If brighter, then create a text image of the same size with transparent background and use black text color. Similarly if darker, use white text color. So in ImageMagick command line, these would be:

Input:

[image]

Pink Undercolor:

```
convert logo.png \
\( -size 110x -background pink -font ubuntu-bold -fill $textcolor label:"Testng" \) \
-gravity northwest -geometry +395+400 -compose over -composite result3.png
```

[image]

Testing (dark region) - Unix syntax:

```
test=`convert logo.png -crop 110x36+395+400 +repage -colorspace gray -format "%[fx:(mean>0.5)?1:0]" info:`
if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then
    textcolor="black"
else
    textcolor="white"
fi
convert logo.png \
\( -size 110x -background none -font ubuntu-bold -fill $textcolor label:"Testng" \) \
-gravity northwest -geometry +395+400 -compose over -composite result1.png
```

[image]

Testing (bright region):

```
test=`convert logo.png -crop 110x36+100+400 +repage -colorspace gray -format "%[fx:(mean>0.5)?1:0]" info:`
if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then
    textcolor="black"
else
    textcolor="white"
fi
convert logo.png \
\( -size 110x -background none -font ubuntu-bold -fill $textcolor label:"Testng" \) \
-gravity northwest -geometry +100+400 -compose over -composite result2.png
```

[image]

Sorry, I do not know Imagick. So someone else may need to help on that.