# Get brightness info of an image from Imagemagic or Graphicmagic

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, aws-lambda

Is there a **specific function** that I can use to retrieve the brightness info of an image using Graphicmagick or Imagemagick. I'm currently using a Node.js aws lambda function to do other operations like resizing the image.

But I was not able to find a correct method to retrieve the brightness info (How dark the image is).

Any help or direction would be really help full.

I reference the following URLs.
[Link 1](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=11304)
[Link 2](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11297)

Comment: There is no detected function for brightness statistics. You have to _calculate_ it. The referring links posted show you how, but what have you tried?

Comment: I thought there should be a direct way of getting those, since the suggested way has more calculation it costs money in my case. That's why I was looking for a direct function/attribute to get the data I need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851731/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method I can think of is to use an `fx` expression with the `.identify` method.

```js
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
var filename = 'rose:'
gm(filename).identify({format:'%[fx:lightness]'}, function(err, info){
   console.log('Lightness pixel value : ' + info);
   //=> "Lightness pixel value : 0.182353"
});
```

As suggested by the reference links, converting image to grayscale might yield more accurate results.

```
var brightness = 0.0;
gm().in(filename).colorspace('GRAY').out('-format').out('%[fx:mean*100]').toBuffer('info', function(err, buffer){
    brightness = parseFloat(buffer.toString())
    console.log('Gray brightness : ' + brightness)
    //=> "Gray brightness : 39.4629"
});
```

Or as Mark pointed out in another question/answer. Converted the image to HSL colorspace might be more flexible.

```
var brightness = 0.0;
gm().in(filename).colorspace('HSL').channel('B').out('-format').out('%[fx:mean*100]').toBuffer('info', function(err, buffer){
    brightness = parseFloat(buffer.toString())
    console.log('Lightness-channel average : ' + brightness)
    //=> "Lightness-channel average : 37.219"
})
```